# AbortError: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()

Tags: javascript, html, audio, promise, playback

iam currenlty trying to fix this javascript code but i cant seem to get it right it stills throws out

> Uncaught (in promise) AbortError: The play() request was interrupted
>   by a call to pause()

and i don't understand whats wrong with it so if you guys could help me out i would be truly happy

Here's the code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="nui://game/ui/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        var audioPlayer = null;

        window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            if (event.data.transactionType == "playSound") {

              if (audioPlayer != null) {
              audioPlayer.pause();
              }

              audioPlayer = new Audio("./sounds/" + event.data.transactionFile + ".ogg");
              audioPlayer.volume = event.data.transactionVolume;

              audioPlayer.play();


            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem myself when playing with sounds. The below code fixed it for me:

```
var soundPromise = audioPlayer.play();

//If the promise exists
if (soundPromise != undefined) {

    soundPromise.then(function(_) {
        //Pause and reset the sound
        sound.pause();
        sound.currentTime = 0;

    });

}
```

Let me know if you have any issues!

Comment: Iam littarly been staring at this code for like 2 hour straight and i dont understand how i could implement this into the code i have right now. Iam kinda braindead atm so if you could help me out once more i would really really appricate it.

Comment: Just put it wherever you're calling `.pause()`.

Comment: @JackBashford On the row where you call `sound.pause();` - Where did you get the `sound` variable?

Comment: That's just whatever the OP is using as their sound - it's just a placeholder example.

Answer (score 0):

This is the auto play issue in the browser: in short, if you do not make some operation (e.g. click, touch) the browser will not allow media to auto start to play.

Can refer to: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

To fix, you should put the calling of `.play()` in a call back function of click a button, e.g.

```
playBtn.onclick = function(){
  audioPlayer.play();
}
```

This is not rather an issue, it is actually a rule.

Comment: It's not an autoplay - you'll see the error the OP gave us was `the play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()`.