# How do I prevent Electron from failing to load video in the background?

Tags: node.js, electron

I have an electron app that generates thumbnails in an offscreen window. That was working until a recent update.

My code is effectively

```js
try {
  const video = document.createElement('video');
  video.src = urlForVideo;
  await video.play();
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

and I get the message

> The play() request was interrupted because video-only background media was paused to save power.

My app needs to generate thumbnails for videos in the background. Sure I can revert to an older version of Electron but is there some way to configure electron to not generate this error?

I tried passing `backgroundThottling: false` as a `webPreferences` flag as documented [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/main/docs/api/structures/web-preferences.md?inline) but that didn't help

Comment: The second answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53735058/aborterror-the-play-request-was-interrupted-by-a-call-to-pause) states that it is an autoplay method that is blocked due to lack of user interaction. Try searching up a way to enable autoplay in electron

Answer (score 0):

After a little search from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53735058/aborterror-the-play-request-was-interrupted-by-a-call-to-pause), it looks like that this is an autoplay method being blocked by chrome due to [lack of user interaction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide).

There is a preference you can set in electron to enable the autoplay method, but please make sure you know what you're doing because it is not recommended to disable the `webSecurity` property.

Try setting the `webSecurity` property to `false` when initializing your window, something like this:

```js
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    webSecurity: false
  }
});

mainWindow.loadURL("http://autoplay-video-url-here.com");
```

If that doesn't work, there is an alternative method where you can pass a *command* to your app (make sure to do it after it's ready):

```js
app.commandLine.appendSwitch("autoplay-policy", "no-user-gesture-required");
```

*This method is a lot more recommended than the other one.*

**Code source**: https://thecodersblog.com/play-video-unmuted-in-electron-app/

If this doesn't work, my second guess is that this message:

> The play() request was interrupted because video-only background media was paused to save power.

Has something to do with any battery-saver preferences on your system.

###### P.S.

I don't know if this was a typo in your post, but you said you tried setting `backgroundThrottling` but it looks like you forgot the "r". If it was an actual typo try re-running it with the correct parameter.